# Extract weight of an item from its description using regex in python

Tags: python, regex

I have a list of product descriptions. for example:

```
 items = ['avuhovi Grillikaapeli 320g','Savuhovi Kisamakkara 320g',
'Savuhovi Raivo 250g', 'AitoMaku str.garl.sal.dres.330ml', 'Rydbergs
 225ml Hollandaise sauce']
```

I want to extract the weights that is, 320g, 320g, 250ml, 330ml. I know we can use regex for this but do not know how to buil regex to extract that. You can see that weights are sometimes in the middle of the description and sometimes having dot(.) as separator rather than space. So, I am confused how to extract.

Thanks for help in advance :)

Comment: How about this one : `[0-9]+(g|ml)`

Comment: I think for the current ones, you may use `re.findall(r'\d+(?:g|ml)\b', s)` to extract multiple occurrences, but you'd need to add more units of measurement if you have more. If there can be only one occurrence in the strings you have, Floran's regex  with `re.search` is enough (still, I'd add a word boundary after the group).

Comment: @FloranGmehlin: Please undelete your answer, just use `re.search` and get `.group()` value. It seems that should work for OP.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew oh I deleted it because it doesnt work fully. only matches `m` and not `ml`

Comment: You used `[]` in the answer, while you use a correct `()` in the comment. `m = re.search(r'[0-9]+(g|ml)', t)` is good enough and then get `m.group()`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: Hi Azfar, did you manage to get this working how you wanted?

Comment: @Sarcoma I used `re.search(r'([0-9]+(g|ml))', t).group(0)`. [0-9] allows the regex to parse for numbers and g|ml|kg allowed me to extract the respective unit.

Comment: That looks pretty much like @FloranGmehlin was correct?

Comment: Actually Floran and Wiktor both were correct when I tried their regex but Floran's code was easy for me to understand and works better in my case.

Answer (score 6):

Here is one solution that may work (using `search` and `group` suggested by Wiktor):

```
>>> for t in items :
...   re.search(r'([0-9]+(g|ml))', t).group(1)
... 
'320g'
'320g'
'250g'
'330ml'
'225ml'
```

Indeed a better solution (thanks Wiktor) would be to test if there is a match :

```
>>> res = []
>>> for t in items :
...   m = re.search(r'(\d+(g|ml))', t)
...   if m:
...     res.append(m.group(1))

print res
```

Comment: I believe you still would want to check if there is a match. So, it is safer to use `m = re.search(r'[0-9]+(g|ml)', t)` and then `if m: res.append(m.group())` (or print, or whatever)

Answer (score 0):

https://regex101.com/r/gy5YTp/4

Match any digit with `\d+` then create a matching but non selecting group with `(?:ml|g)` this will match ml or g.

```
import re

items = ['avuhovi Grillikaapeli 320g', 'Savuhovi 333ml Kisamakkara 320g', 'Savuhovi Raivo 250g', 'AitoMaku str.garl.sal.dres.330ml', 'Rydbergs 225ml Hollandaise sauce']

groupedWeights = [re.findall('(\d+(?:ml|g))', i) for i in items]
flattenedWeights = [y for x in groupedWeights for y in x]

print(flattenedWeights)
```

The match that we make returns a list of lists of weights found so we need to flatten that with `[y for x in groupedWeights for y in x]`

That is if you ever have more than one weight in an element. Otherwise we can take the first element of each list like this.

```
weights = [re.findall('(\d+(?:ml|g))', i)[0] for i in items]
```

Comment: This gives only the `g` or `ml` part

Comment: Ha oh yeah the regex link matches hold on

Comment: @FloranGmehlin Pretty new to regex in Python how would I fix this is now has two capturing groups, is that what you are using group for?

Comment: `findall` will return a list of tuples with all matching groups (see : https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) as for `search` creates a matching object from which you can get the desired group